# Herokuで"Deploy Branch"を実行した際に発生するエラーを解決したい

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord

作成したDiscord BotをHerokuを使って永続稼働させたいです。
今GitHubと連携させてやっているのですが、やり方が合っているかわからないです。
一応GitHubにrepositoryを作成し、VScodeで作ったプログラムとその他諸々のファイルなどを作成したファイルに移してVScodeのターミナルでGitPushしました。
この時点でやり方など間違えていたらすいません。

"Deploy Branch" を実行したときに出たエラーコード

```
Python app detected
 !     Requested runtime (Python-3.9.1) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

リンクによると、

> 上記のいずれかのバージョンを使用して「Requested runtime is not available for this stack」というエラーが表示される場合は、アプリが最新バージョンのPythonビルドパックを使用していることを確認してください。

とのことです。
リンクに書いてある様に、

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
heroku buildpacks
```

のコマンドを実行してみましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　今コマンド試してみたのですが、多分うまく行きました！　　　　試しに実行してみたのですが、同じエラーが出てしまいました。。　何か更新みたいなのをしないとダメなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

そのボットのルートダイレクトリにruntime.txt というファイルがあります。その中の Python-3.9.1 を`python-3.9.1`に変えてやってみてください。